# Regular expression using non-greedy matching -- confusing result

Tags: regex

I thought I understood how the non-greedy modifier works, but am confused by the following result:

- Regular Expression:  `(,\S+?)_sys$`
- Test String: `abc,def,ghi,jkl_sys`
- Desired result:     `,jkl_sys`    <- last field including comma
- Actual result:      `,def,ghi,jkl_sys`

Use case is that I have a comma separated string whose last field will end in "_sys" (e.g. ,sometext_sys).   I want to match only the last field and only if it ends with _sys.

I am using the non-greedy (?) modifier to return the shortest possible match (only the last field including the comma), but it returns all but the first field (i.e. the longest match).

What am I missing?

I used https://regex101.com/ to test, in case you want to see a live example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you're looking for the a string that ends with "_sys" and it has to be at the end of the source string, and it has to be preceded by a comma.

```
,\s*(\w+_sys)$
```

I added the `\s*` to allow for optional whitespace after the comma.

No non-greedy modifiers necessary.

The parens are around `\w+_sys` so you can capture just that string, without the comma and optional whitespace.

Comment: That also does what I need.   Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
,[^,]+_sys$
```

The pattern matches:

- `,` Match the last comma
- `[^,]+` Match 1 + occurrences of any char except `,`
- `_sys` Match literally
- `$` End of string

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Qezkuz/1).

If you don't want to match newlines and whitespaces:

```
,[^\s,]+_sys$
```

Comment: That does what I need.   Thanks.